# 230VAC dimmer MOSFET failure at surge test

Tags: mosfet, dimmer, surge-protection

Our dimmer prototypes work fine, but fails surge test, as per 61000-4-5, 1/50us.

Circuit is isolated dimmer for 230VAC different types of bulbs. It uses 2x N MOSFET as switch. V503 detects zero crossings. N504/N505 are isolated drivers, in parallel to provide more power=faster switching.

Mains side passes test for 0,5kV, 1kV and 1,5kV L-N, tested in OFF and ON states. Bulb side fails for 0,5kV L-N @ ON state (because of peak current), passes 1,5kV @ OFF state (voltage suppressor works). 50% dimming is not tested yet.

What I tested, but not helps: protect each transistor with separate varistor, without LC filter (L503/C503), without CMChoke L502 on mains side, additional gate-source capacitors 2n2, additional gate-source TVS 15V bi-dir, moving output N before L502.
Most often only one of FETs gets broken (but not always the same) with almost shorted 3 terminals, no smoke or package holes. Load is 60W tungsten bulb.

I have limited space on PCB and components prices, can't add second CMC.

L503 is 470uH/2A

[image: dimmer schematic]

Comment: The location of your CMC is somewhat odd. Is there anything else connected to that branch besides the optocoupler?

Comment: What’s the value of L503? What if you make a symmetrical Pi filter instead of LC? Can you cheat and stop switching during any overvoltage transient? RC snubber across each MOSFET? Can you have a varistor to ground? What does the voltage waveform across drain-source look like during testing?

Comment: Model the surge and the circuit and simulate it. Examine what’s doing the damage.

Comment: @EdgarBrown I agree. There's nothing more there. Moving output N before L502 not helps.

Comment: @winny L503 is 470uH/2A. I tested ON/OFF states, not 50% or any other. I'll try symetric Pi or snubber. Varistor to ground - You mean to isolated side?

Comment: @Bogumil Did some simulation for you but not enough for an answer. It's however clear that if you tried to sense any overvoltage (transient) and turn off the MOSFETs, you are in a far better position. Adding more capacitance "inside" of L503 will have a severe penalty for high switching frequencies. What switching frequency are you running at?

Comment: @winny Max. switching is 100Hz (for 50Hz mains), but not tested yet.

Comment: Where exactly are you injecting the 61000-4-5 impulse and with reference to what, line to line or line to ground?

Comment: @dougp01 With L-N I mean line to line

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is ( no pun intended) the lower main line injection of 0.5kV with a 1us rise time and Miller capacitance coupling of impulse voltage back to the gate drive is probably exceeding the Vgs levels. This rise time equates to a the driving spectral energy band of \$f_{-3dB}=0.35/t_R= 350kHz\$

You have a CM choke on 1 side but not the other. It needs a CM choke between both lines to raise the CM impedance and a differential choke to raise each line impedance due to lightning rise times.

- These can be SMD CM chokes types with sufficient voltage rating.
- You can also add 500 Ohm [ferrite beads](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/filters/ferrite-beads-and-chips/841?FV=1f140000%2Cffe00349%2C5400dc%2C540040&quantity=0&ColumnSort=-1000003&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=500) at 350KHz.
  e.g. https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tdk-corporation/VFS5045VA111/445-181417-2-ND/9817660